# How can we change the angular js error consoles

Tags: angularjs

I am using a MEAN stack project. When errors and exceptions occurred on angular controllers, the Angular Js logs it in the browser's console.
On the production server, it is impossible to catch those errors.
So, I want to implement a mailing system using google SMTP which send me the error stack of the error or exception occurred.

I want to report browser errors to my server.
How it can be achieved?

Comment: good idea, where are you stuck in implementing it?

Comment: On the server or on the client? Because angularjs is working on client. You can use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler

Comment: I want to report browser errors to my server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link could help you then you can send the error by Web Api to your server.

[Catch All Errors in Angularjs App](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/catch-all-errors-in-angular-app/)